# How to make Windows store application non-fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, fullscreen, windows-store-apps

Question:

I'm experimenting with a JavaScript application for Windows store.
So far, everything works perfectly.

I wrote a little application that removes line numbers from source code that starts with line numbers ;)

However, I do not find it useful that this app is forced to fullscreen mode.
This is against the concept of multitasking, since I expect this app to be used on the desktop while programming and wanting to copy-paste something from the internet, and not on an average tablet.

Is there any way to create a windows store application that is non-fullscreen ?

```
window.resizeTo( 640, 480 );
```

certainly isn't working.

Comment: Apart from fullscreen mode, there is a snapped mode available for WinRT apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx. You can snap your app to side while working on desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a very specific exception, you cannot control the size of your app.  There is no way to do what you are trying to do.  Only the user can control the size of your app, and they have specific, limited things that they can do (snapping, rotation, and moving to other monitors).

If your app is snapped—that is, if it's docked to the left or right side of the screen—you can request to unsnap.  You can't programmatically snap yourself to either side; you can only ask to unsnap yourself to take over the full screen.

Comment: Hmmm, actually the apps ARE multitasking. The only restriction being that you cant have more than 2 visible on the screen at one time, and thats only for the metro style apps delivered via marketplace.

Comment: @RobCurr: Yea, technically that's true, but usability... From a usability standpoint, requiring full screen is not very different from single-tasking. After all, WindowsStore apps would be far more interesting to write (or sell respectively) if they could run on the desktop as well...

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that you have decided to create it for the windows store. There are two types of tablets that will be coming out, the Windows RT tablet which will limit you to only installing stuff from the store, and the x86 variants which are essentially full PC's in tablet form. The second type can allow you to install windowed applications that run just like on the desktop as well as the windows store applications which will all be in fullscreen.

If you definitely think you still want to do this as a store app you should look into the sharing paradigm that Microsoft is trying to promote. Essentially you expose a bunch of 'contracts' for your application to send and receive different types of information such as pictures, text etc. Any app that has a matching contract for that datatype will be able to consume or provide that type of data. That combined with the ability for the app to snap to one side or the other should give you enough flexibility to acheive what you described in your first post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  It will launch in full screen.  The only exception to this rule is if a user has already and snapped an app to a quarter of the screen.  At this point yours would snap to the remaining 3/4's.